# I want to call stopservice when exiting the app

Tags: android

I'm aware many questions regarding how to stop a service have been asked before, but I didn't find one addressing my particular problem.

In my application I have a number of activities that communicate with one central service. For each activity I call bindService() in their onResume() methods and unbindService() in their onPause() methods. The issue I'm having with this is that each time I switch between two activities the service is destroyed and then recreated from scratch.

In order to address this I have considered calling startService() in onCreate(), to ensure the service remains active.

My question is, where should I put the stopService()-Method to ensure it is called when leaving the application? Or alternatively, is there a another way to keep the service running as I switch between two activities, without relying startService()?

Comment: "In my application I have a number of activities that communicate with one central service" -- you do not need a service for that. You only need a service if you wish to do something in the background.

Answer (score 0):

> For each activity I call bindService() in their onResume() methods and unbindService() in their onPause() methods. The issue I'm having with this is that each time I switch between two activities the service is destroyed and then recreated from scratch.

If you're just trying to access some shared object that all activities will use, binding and unbinding from a Service is not the proper solution, for the reasons you've already outlined. Just use some kind of Singleton that is always available for any activity that needs it.